# How to perform different database queries based on the user login

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on Flask project. I want to query a database to display different data based on the user login. I have some group of employees in my database which is divided into teams:
- Developers
- Systems analyst
- Technical support e.t.c.

I want to display each team's data for their respective supervisors based on the supervisor login. Currently, am performing this with if else statement.

```
@app.route('/employee')
def employee():
    cur = connection.cursor()
    emp_num == request.form.emp_num(emp_num)
    if emp_num = '1010':
        cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM emp_data WHERE team = "dev"'''')
    elif emp_num = '1122':
        cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM emp_data WHERE team = "analyst"'''')
    else:
        return 'Data not found'
```

The code is something like this.  Is there any way to do this automatically based on the supervisor login credentials or something better?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your quesiton

Comment: I would look into the `Flask-Login` package as well, since this gives you the `current_user` global context, but it might be overachieving what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mangohero1 I will check the Flask-Login package.

Answer (score 0):

This should cut you some lines:

```
@app.route('/employee')
def employee():
    cur = connection.cursor()
    emp_num == request.form.emp_num(emp_num)
    emp_nums = {'1010': 'dev', '1122': 'analyst'}
    if emp_num in emp_nums:
        cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM emp_data WHERE team = "{}"'''.format(emp_nums[emp_num]))
    else:
        return 'Data not found'
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to check the existence of the supervisor in the same table and make the query instead of defining it into a Dict? Thank you

Comment: Well if you have all the combinations of teams and ids you can create dict from that and save yourself from typing

Comment: I have that data in my database. I was looking for if there is a way to do that in my SQL query statement.

Comment: How can i perform this using SqlAlchemy.